# Not Booting after trying to re-install Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I update Ubuntu from LTS to LTS and have for years on a dual boot system now with Windows 10. The update to Ubuntu 22.04 has caused many problems including the ACPI, not closing down, unable to double-click files to open, many USB errors, not backing up etc. I decided to re-install Ubuntu 22.04 following an interesting article. I downloaded a fresh copy, checked the checksum and tried to install. As seen in other articles the re-install option is not there, only an install alongside the current version necessitating a partition change. I quit out of it. Now I get a blank screen. As I use UEFI booting an article told me to hit Esc for Grub, this took me into BIOS. I tried a Boot-Repair USB which booted once only and I chose the option of fixing most problems and was offered a pastebin file http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YDpTgXB2nv/ now saved. I always get the first password page set up for dual booting but nothing from there. What do I need to do to get the system booting and how do I get 22.04 to work properly. I am desperate. The last working backup was a month ago on a separate disk. Any help would be very gratefully received.

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p6,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


Mount nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/boot/efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p6/etc/default/grub

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of nvme0n1p6 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0002,0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,31cbdb32-faec-4219-9b8a-bf9c8c4e75c8,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...w................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,31cbdb32-faec-4219-9b8a-bf9c8c4e75c8,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO}.......E.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .U.D.i.s.k. .5...0.0....................A..........................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L..........BO..NO........k.A.D.A.T.A. .S.X.8.2.0.0.P.N.P....................A..........................................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.K.3.2.2.L.A.H.1.2.P.1........BO..NO........o.S.S.D. .1.T.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.9.C.6.E.7.5.2.9.0.2.0.2.1.4.0.9.3. .3........BO..NO........[.B.r.o.t.h.e.r. .D.C.P.-.J.4.1.2.0.D.W. .1...0.0....................A..........................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.B.R.O.L.7.F.1.1.7.6.4.2........BO
Boot0003* UEFI: General UDisk 5.00, Partition 1 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,GPT,65f52d4b-35f0-47c0-bc59-f57f8be5b66f,0x800,0x77f7df)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 uname -r
5.3.0-28-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0002,0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,31cbdb32-faec-4219-9b8a-bf9c8c4e75c8,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...w................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,31cbdb32-faec-4219-9b8a-bf9c8c4e75c8,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO}.......E.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .U.D.i.s.k. .5...0.0....................A..........................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L..........BO..NO........k.A.D.A.T.A. .S.X.8.2.0.0.P.N.P....................A..........................................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.K.3.2.2.L.A.H.1.2.P.1........BO..NO........o.S.S.D. .1.T.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.9.C.6.E.7.5.2.9.0.2.0.2.1.4.0.9.3. .3........BO..NO........[.B.r.o.t.h.e.r. .D.C.P.-.J.4.1.2.0.D.W. .1...0.0....................A..........................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.B.R.O.L.7.F.1.1.7.6.4.2........BO
Boot0003* UEFI: General UDisk 5.00, Partition 1 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,GPT,65f52d4b-35f0-47c0-bc59-f57f8be5b66f,0x800,0x77f7df)..BO
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.0.5-060005-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.0.5-060005-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p6/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at 
    sector 558456112 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not 
    be found at this location.
 => libparted MBR boot code is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p6
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Intel Corporation from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 5.12 from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0002,0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,31cbdb32-faec-4219-9b8a-bf9c8c4e75c8,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...w................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,31cbdb32-faec-4219-9b8a-bf9c8c4e75c8,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO}.......E.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .U.D.i.s.k. .5...0.0....................A..........................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L..........BO..NO........k.A.D.A.T.A. .S.X.8.2.0.0.P.N.P....................A..........................................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.K.3.2.2.L.A.H.1.2.P.1........BO..NO........o.S.S.D. .1.T.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.9.C.6.E.7.5.2.9.0.2.0.2.1.4.0.9.3. .3........BO..NO........[.B.r.o.t.h.e.r. .D.C.P.-.J.4.1.2.0.D.W. .1...0.0....................A..........................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.B.R.O.L.7.F.1.1.7.6.4.2........BO
Boot0003* UEFI: General UDisk 5.00, Partition 1 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,GPT,65f52d4b-35f0-47c0-bc59-f57f8be5b66f,0x800,0x77f7df)..BO

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
c152ec201c37b6e97bbc2207e49d1271   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
4b3da9137970804fc849e44ae90c4bb8   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
63e2430cf26b13f48ae8de8e71097abb   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p6   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 253FAD48-3982-11EC-AA2F-DA7780B3BD33
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616  519370349  519130734 247.6G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 519370752  520429567    1058816   517M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 520431616  632880845  112449230  53.6G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p6 632881152 2000408575 1367527424 652.1G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xb6d3912a
      Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1        2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G 83 Linux
Disk sdc: 3.8 GiB, 4026531840 bytes, 7864320 sectors
Disk identifier: F59B6FAC-EDFF-439E-AAE0-AE415B5F5397
      Start     End Sectors  Size Type
sdc1   2048 7864286 7862239  3.8G Microsoft basic data
Disk zram0: 3.9 GiB, 4181577728 bytes, 1020893 sectors
Disk zram1: 3.9 GiB, 4181577728 bytes, 1020893 sectors
Disk zram2: 3.9 GiB, 4181577728 bytes, 1020893 sectors
Disk zram3: 3.9 GiB, 4181577728 bytes, 1020893 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA SSD 1TB:;
1:1049kB:1000GB:1000GB:ext4::;
sdc:4027MB:scsi:512:512:gpt:General UDisk:;
1:1049kB:4027MB:4025MB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:ADATA SX8200PNP:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:266GB:266GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:266GB:266GB:542MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:266GB:324GB:57.6GB:ext4::;
6:324GB:1024GB:700GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      ext4     ef853352-bc2d-42cb-8f86-5c92aa1efbe5 b6d3912a-01                                      
sdc                                                                                                        
└─sdc1      vfat     1094-A56A                            65f52d4b-35f0-47c0-bc59-f57f8be5b66f BOOT-REPAIR Main Data Partition
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     1648-8F29                            31cbdb32-faec-4219-9b8a-bf9c8c4e75c8             EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               38067e9d-77bd-4e6e-bcad-42b660f615a2             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     2E944B6A944B341D                     a88ad765-e35b-4f98-8240-e9ed46071f25             Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     369E44509E440B37                     725f93f4-6ca9-46d1-98b4-047c55fae044             
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4     09783151-c54a-463f-91da-a9e13b80be47 f0b34793-ba10-458e-a030-2fac76bff732             
└─nvme0n1p6 ext4     8c0727b7-f3bc-4084-aa03-424377089947 cc2cf495-1fca-49f9-84ab-5ab90a350f82             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  64.9M  32% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3 170.2G  31% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4  88.8M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5    49G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6   551G   9% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/sda1      772.8G  11% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sdc1        2.9G  23% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 8c0727b7-f3bc-4084-aa03-424377089947 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p6/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   8c0727b7-f3bc-4084-aa03-424377089947
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.0.5-060005-generic   8c0727b7-f3bc-4084-aa03-424377089947
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic   8c0727b7-f3bc-4084-aa03-424377089947
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-53-generic   8c0727b7-f3bc-4084-aa03-424377089947
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-1648-8F29
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p6/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=8c0727b7-f3bc-4084-aa03-424377089947 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=1648-8F29  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p6: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 301.781257629 = 324.035158016  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 876.659194946 = 941.305643008  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 305.010753632 = 327.502802944  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-53-generic                 1
 876.659194946 = 941.305643008  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic                 2
 306.128414154 = 328.702881792  boot/vmlinuz-6.0.5-060005-generic              2
 305.010753632 = 327.502802944  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 328.421871185 = 352.640299008  boot/initrd.img                                4
 868.645061493 = 932.700532736  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic              1
 328.421871185 = 352.640299008  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic              4
 328.611358643 = 352.843759616  boot/initrd.img-6.0.5-060005-generic           2
 868.645061493 = 932.700532736  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 15  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 21  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Aug 12  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

====================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)

========================= sdc1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
```

Comment: What brand/model system? It says it is not updating UEFI, but you do have Ubuntu entry. From UEFI boot menu can you boot Ubuntu entry?  I have lots of SSD/HDD space so always have two LTS versions installed, but to overwrite an existing install, you need to use something else and choose existing / as new /. If you want to keep your data in the existing partition do not check the format box. It will overwrite with defaults for all system settings & most user settings, so good backups still required. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a Chinese Kingdel micro system with a Skybay (Lenovo) motherboard, Ryzen 5 Processor and 32 Gb ddr4. I twin boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10. I get the first password for the dual boot, the Ami Bios screen, then a flashing cursor in the top left corner. If I change the boot order I can get back to install another version of Ubuntu, is that the way to go? I think by initiating the install to the point I could not overwrite the old version, the install disk has deleted the grub boot record. Can I get that back first then try to fix the problems?

Comment: Booting live installer should not overwrite an install's grub. But installing or reinstalling from live installer will overwrite grub in ESP and update UEFI if UEFI settings allow it. Some need UEFI settings changed & Windows updates may have reset to defaults and those you did before need to be redone. And install actually installs grub as last task. You can repair grub in an install from live installer using chroot or Boot-Repair. Newer users find Boot-Repair easier. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thanks for your help oldfred. I cannot explain how but going into Bios to change booting sequence to install the second copy of Ubuntu 22.04, a new booting option appeared for my M.2 SSD into Ubuntu and the normal boot screen appeared. Now I will try to split my Home folder from my Ubuntu partition so this does not occur again and reload Ubuntu.